# Java. Cast generic List to list of objects from factory

Tags: java, generics, jersey

Is it possible to cast List Objects to List of Objects from Factory pattern?

I have a Jersey REST endpoint and I migrate data from one environment to another. I wish to post some list of Object and cast them to right object taken from factory pattern

```
@Path("/migrateTableAtOnce")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public <T> Response saveObjectIntoDb(List<T> listOfObj) {

    // if listOfObj.getTableName() == "MW_ID_GENERATOR" tableOject gets new MwIdGenerator()
    myEntity tableObject = myEntityFactory.getTable(listOfObj.getTableName());


    return Response.status(201).entity("ok").build();

}
```

Is it possible that I have only one post method which that generic List. I have 20 objects which I need to transfer and I dont want to write 20 post methods :( I dont know how to do it exactly.

One of my method looks like that:

```
@POST
@Path("/migrateTableAtOnceMwIdGenerator")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveObjectIntoDb(List<MwIdGenerator> listOfObj) {

    Boolean result = false;

    String dbResponse ="";
    try {
        dbResponse = obtainFacade().saveToDb(listOfObj);
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.status(201).entity(result+" "+dbResponse).build();

}
```

Is there no better solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the body as a custom object, and have a list within that object like;

```
@POST
@Path("/migrateTableAtOnceMwIdGenerator")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveObjectIntoDb(CustomObject object) {

    List <Stuff>list = object.getList();
```

and the object

```
public class CustomObject extends Serializable {

public List <Stuff>sList = null;
public List <OtherStuff>osList = null;
public List <TheBestStuff>tbsList = null; //etcetc

public List getList ()
{
    return list;
}

public void setList(List <Stuff>list)
{
    this.list = list;
}

public List getOsList ()
{
    return osList ;
}

public void setList(List <OtherStuff>osList)
{
    this.osList  = osList;
}

public List getTbsList  ()
{
    return tbsList;
}

public void setTbsList(List <TheBestStuff>tbsList)
{
    this.tbsList = tbsList;
}
```

and Jersey can parse the `json` object into your custom object, provided that you can pass the fields of that class as json. Seeing as you're passing the data with `json`, you're limited as to your implimentation as json only covers `String`, `int`, `boolean` and simple date, but you can pass most values as `String` and then parse.

Comment: thank you but why extends Serializable ? What should I import?

Comment: just import java.io.Serializable; I *think* Jersey needs it to be able to marshall custom objects.

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any way to put here generic List? public List <Stuff>list = null;

Comment: It looks like you might have to make a number of entries for your custom lists in your pojo - reflected in my edit.